# Geometric Distribution - deriving the expected value

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-distributions

So I was trying to derive the expected value of the Geom(p) distribution, however, it seems that I am always off with a negative value. (i.e. getting $-\frac{1}{p}$ instead of $\frac{1}{p}$)

My attempt was as follow:

> X ~ Geom(p)
>
>  $E[X] = \sum_{k=1}^\infty k(1-p)^{k-1}p = p\sum_{k=1}^\infty k(1-p)^{k-1}$
>
>  Then by Sum of Infinite Series $\sum (1-p)^k = \frac{1}{p}$
>
>  By taking derivatives or both side, we may get $\sum k(1-p)^{k-1} = -\frac{1}{p^2}$
>
>  Substitute it back, we get E[X] = $p * -\frac{1}{p^2} = -\frac{1}{p}$

However, if we substitute (1-p) by q first..

> $E[X] = \sum_{k=1}^\infty kq^{k-1}p = p\sum_{k=1}^\infty kq^{k-1}$
>
>  $\sum q^k = \frac{1}{1-q}$
>
>  By taking derivatives or both side, we may get $\sum k(q)^{k-1} = \frac{1}{(1-q)^2}$ as there will be a negative sign from Chain Rule
>
>  Substitute it back, we get E[X] = $p * \frac{1}{p^2} = \frac{1}{p}$

I wonder where does the negative sign comes from if I use $1 - p$ instead of $q$

 Or it's just my problem with basic calculus...

Comment: Derivative of $\sum (1-p)^k$ wrt $p$ is $-\sum k(1-p)^{k-1}$, so you miss a negative sign.

Answer (score 1):

1. the easy way to compute your mean is to observe that, by definition (in this case the variable is defined on non negative integers...)

$$\mathbb{E}[X]=\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\mathbb{P}[X \geq k]=1+(1-p)+(1-p)^2+...=\frac{1}{1-(1-p)}=\frac{1}{p}$$

2. An alternative method, is the following

always by definition,

$\mathbb{E}[X]=\sum_x xp(x)$ and, of course $P(X=x)=pq^{x-1}$ having set $q=1-p$

Thus the mean can be calculated as follows:

$$\mathbb{E}[X]=p\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}xq^{x-1}=p\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}\frac{d}{dq}q^x=p\frac{d}{dq}\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}q^x=p\frac{d}{dq}\frac{q}{1-q}=p\frac{1}{(1-q)^2}=\frac{p}{[1-(1-p)]^2}=\frac{1}{p}$$

it is understood that I prefer the first method...

Comment: I didn't get method 1 at first, so I'll say something for ppl like me: P[X≥k] = P[X=1] + 2P[X=2] + 3P[X=3] + ... = kP[X], so it satisfies the definition for expected value.